# Script working in PS3 but not in PS2 , I can't find the exact error "Bad Argument to operator '-gt'

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

my script to find files bigger than x works fine for me and my powershell 3.0. But on our server we just have powershell 2.0 and I can't make it work correctly.

The error is the following :

```
Bad Argument to Operator '-gt' Could not compare "3841" to "10MB". Error cannot convert "10MB" to type "System.Int64" Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."".
```

My script is here, I tried to change the 10MB value to just "10"  but than it compares to kb I guess. that's not what i wanted!  Any ideas?

```
Param(
  [ValidateScript({test-path -path $_ -pathtype container})]
  [string]$targetfolder,
  [string]$size
)

function getfilesbigger 
{
$colItems =  (get-childitem  "$targetfolder" -recurse | where {$_.length -gt "$size" } | tee-object -variable allfiles | measure-object -property length -sum)
$allfiles | foreach-object {write-host $_.FullName ("{0:N2}" -f ($_.Length / 1MB)) "MB" -ForegroundColor "green" }
write-host "Collected all files bigger than $size from folder $targetfolder " -foregroundcolor "darkgreen"
"Number of files: "+ $colItems.count + [Environment]::NewLine + "Size of all files "+"{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB" 
}

getfilesbigger
```

Comment: Did you step in a debugger? what's in $size?

Comment: ah sorry, in size i enter "10mb" or "10GB"

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `size` has been defined explicitly as a string:

```
Param(  ...   
[string]$size)
```

Thus, Powershell won't convert 10mb automatically to integer 10485760 as usual, but instead uses it as a string. For working version, just use int like so,

```
Param(
  [ValidateScript({test-path -path $_ -pathtype container})]
  [string]$targetfolder,
  [int]$size
)
```

**Edit:**

It works on my 2.0 environment well. Try adding a `.GetType()` call to see what's going on. Like so,

```
function getfilesbigger 
{
$size.gettype()
$colItems = ...
```

The result for gettype call ought to be

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                BaseType
-------- -------- ----                --------
True     True     Int32               System.ValueType
```

What do you get?

Comment: Cannot process arguemtn transformation on parameter "size". Cannot convert value "10MB" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."   -- that's what i get after the change to [int]

Comment: Remove the quotes around `$size` in your script. The quotes convert it to a string.

Comment: i get the same result when i enter "10"  for $size   but "10MB" doesn't work. and then he collects all files again and not the files bigger than :/

Comment: ok i am now back on that problem : when i run a simple command like : get-childitem directory  | where {$_.length -gt 10mb}  it is working....but somehow in the function it wont work. I will play around with that

Comment: when i hardcode the parameter, it works. somehow he can't load the parameters correctly from my batch file.

Comment: sure, it's the same as you had